# Парсинг docker-compose.yml с помощью Python

Tags: python, парсер, docker-compose

Хотелось бы найти готовое решение (библиотеку) для решения задачи парсинга файлов `docker-compose.yml` с помощью python. Чтобы не писать собственных костыльных решений. Погуглив, не нашел такого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть либа для этого. [PyYaml](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation).

```
import yaml

with open("docker-compose.yml", 'r') as stream:
    try:
        doc = yaml.load(stream)
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)
    print (doc["services"])
```